# Laravel class isn't in polymorphic relationship with other class

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I am working on a polymorphic relationship between these classes in my small project: Submissions (same as posts), Comments and Users.

The problem is, I am able to gather all comments by relying on Submission model, for example:

`$submissions = Submission::with('comments')->get()->find( $submission );`

But, if I try something like this in tinker:

`$users = User::with( 'comments' )->get();`

I get all the users data, but no comments show up:

```
         comments: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3003
           all: [],
         },
```

Here's all the code of relations between models:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'commentable_id', 'commentable_type', 'text' ];

    public function commentable() {
        return morphTo();
    }
}
```

Now this is being added inside Submission and User model:

```
    public function comments() {
        return $this->morphMany( Comment::class, 'commentable' );
    }
```

In Submission model I am using protected $guarded = []; to deal with Mass Assignment and I don't call it inside user model.

I hope you can tell me what am I doing wrong since somehow I can't access user model by comment model and vice versa.
Thanks in advance!

edit: Here's a code of creation of a comment:

```
    public function store( Submission $submission ) {

        $data = request()->validate([
           'text' => [ 'required', 'string', 'max:255' ]
        ]);

        $id = $submission->comments()->create([ 'text' => request()->text ]);
        dd( $submission, $data );

    }
```

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. Do you actually have any comments in db where`commentable_type` is `App\User`? Your code for creating a comment is only for submission comments.

Comment: Actually, that might be a problem. I have a couple of created comments and commentable_type is Submission::class, not User::class since I didn't find a way to add both, but I need them both in this case, and can you give me a hint how to create a comment for both User and a Submission? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Relation `morphMany` is one-to-many relation, like `hasMany`. So one comment can belong to a submission or a user, not both. One option is to create separate comments for submission and user (for the user do the same as for submission `$user->comments()->->create([...])`). Second option is to use [many-to-many polymorphic relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations), where one comment can belong to multiple submissions and users.

Comment: Thank you, now I have made a relationship with user, but the problem is the way I create the comment:

`$id = auth()->user()->comments()->create( $data );`

If I call the code above, I can only access comment by user model, if I use this:
`$submission->comments()->create( $data );`
I can only access comment by submission model.
Can you tell me how to make them being available to both submission and user model?

Comment: Yes you can do it with `morphToMany`. See how you can do it in the link in my answer.